# GEE: Is ee.Reducer.mean() can ignore NULL values?

Tags: google-earth-engine, reducers

I'm trying to create a time-series of NDVI for 6 sub-regions.
I've downloaded the relevant Sentinel-2 images, and filtered the region containing these 6 sub-regions, filtered the time-period and performed cloud mask.
Now, I'm using *ui.Chart.image.series* - to calculate the mean NDVI value for day for each of the 6 sub-regions, so I used *ee.Reducer.mean()* all over the pixels of the sub-region. Since I masked out cloud pixels in each image, I don't want to OMIT the dates where the cloud-masked bands returned NULL, but to perform the mean with only the NON-NULL pixels. Is it possible?

Comment: That is the default behavior. You can show yourself this by placing your region over a source area that cotnains a mix of masked and unmasked pixels; you will notice that you are returned a null value only if the source area is entirely masked. This might help https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_reduce_region